# assuming uninitialized heap memory is initialized to zero when using mmap?

Tags: c, heap-memory, virtual-memory

We know that While `.bss` memory locations (such as uninitialized global C variables) are always initialized to zeros by the loader, this is not true for heap memory. A common error is to assume that heap memory is initialized to zero.

But what about the allocated memory obtained by `mmap`? We can request heap memory by calling `mmap` to map an arean in the heap with an anonymous file(demand-zero pages), so in this case we can safely assume that heap memory is initialized to zero?

And also, `malloc` actually calls `mmap` internally to request the memory for large size of allocations, and for small size of allocations, `malloc` still calls `sbrk`/`brk` internally. For the latter, we certainly cannot assume that heap memory is initialized to zero.

so for large size of allocations when `malloc` actually calls `mmap` internally, we can still assume that heap memory is initialized to zero? I know it is still not a good practice and we shouldn't read assume 0 under all circustanmances, but I just want to make sure my theory is correct so that I know my understanding of `mmap` is correct.

Comment: I would advise you to use `calloc` if you want any guarantees that the memory is set to zero.

Comment: I'm not qualified to answer this question, but don't assume anything that is not documented.

Comment: Who says that _"malloc still calls sbrk/brk internally"_? It may be true for some specific implementations.

Comment: IF uninitialized variables go into `.bss`, then they're zero-initialized. **IF**. It's a valid compiler choice, because you can overwrite those zeroes, and C only guarantees that uninitialized variables are writeable. You can't assume uninitialized vars are readable, let alone that the value is zero.

Comment: @MSalters 6.9.2/2: "A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier `static`, constitutes a _tentative definition_. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer equal to 0."?

Comment: @Ian: True, so that's your typical initialized variable.

Comment: @MSalters So what sort of uninitialized variables (with internal or external linkage or static storage duration) could be non-readable or have a non-zero initial value?

Comment: @IanAbbott: `_Thread_local` ? That's a storage class specifier, so your quoted part does not apply to those.

Comment: @MSalters OTOH, C18 6.2.4/4 says that `_Thread_local` objects' stored values are initialized when the thread is started, so presumably they have to be initialized with _something_. Perhaps the standard is lacking in clarity here.

Comment: @MSalters On further inspection of C18, initial values of `_Thread_local` objects without explicit initializers is dealt with by 6.7.9/10, so indeed they are initialized to zero.

Answer (score 1):

> We know that While .bss memory locations (such as uninitialized global C variables) are always initialized to zeros by the loader...

I don't know that - could be the loader, could be a language's startup code linked into the program (e.g. "crt0.o"), could be the OS/kernel providing a "new pages are zeroed"  guarantee where loader doesn't have to bother.

> But what about the allocated memory obtained by mmap?

Whose `mmap()` used how?

For POSIX; the spec doesn't include `mmap()`  being used directly to allocate memory. Instead you're supposed to get a file descriptor for an opened "memory object" (e.g. from "`posix_typed_mem_open()`") and then map the memory object using its file descriptor; and the specs for functions to create a "memory object" mostly just say (very paraphrased) "blah blah, implementation defined, blah blah, sorry our spec didn't exist until after it was too late to matter". Because of this it has nothing to say about whether the area is zeroed or not.

For Linux, `mmap(..., MAP_ANONYMOUS)` gives you zeroed pages and `mmap(..., MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_UNINITIALIZED)` probably won't.

For Windows you don't use `mmap()` to allocate memory - you use `VirtualAlloc()` instead, which guarantees the new memory is zeroed.

Every other OS may do whatever else it felt like.

In general; a multi-tasking OS has to worry about security problems (e.g. data still in memory that was freed by one process being accessible after its allocated by a different process) and will fill the pages (with zeros) for security reasons (and convenience).

> so for large size of allocations when malloc actually calls mmap internally, we can still assume that heap memory is initialized to zero?

You can assume whatever you like until you find out that the assumption is wrong. This includes the assumption that `malloc()` calls `mmap()` internally (under some conditions or under any conditions). For example, a C library could just reserve a huge amount of space in the program's `.bss` and use that for `malloc()`, so that `malloc()` never uses `mmap()` or `sbrk()` (or `VirtualAlloc()` or ...) at all.

If you do know that `malloc()` got the underlying memory from somewhere that does guarantee the memory is filled with zeros (which is almost impossible to do given that you could get a mixture of old memory and new memory); then you still can't assume that `malloc()` (or any other part of the language's run-time environment - startup code, C libraries, etc) didn't temporarily use the memory for some meta-data, and still can't assume that memory allocated from `malloc()` is still zeroed by the time you get it.

Note that the heap may optimize `calloc()` so that if it knows that the memory is already filled with zeros (because it kept track, and also knows the underlying memory originally came from somewhere that provides a guarantee) it doesn't fill the memory with zeros for no reason. Essentially, `calloc()` is "`malloc()` with a guarantee" (and not "`malloc()` followed by `memset()`").

Comment: `malloc` on Windows may very well use `HeapAlloc` without passing `HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY`. So on Windows you don't have the guarantee either. `calloc` could then be optimized to call `HeapAlloc` with `HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY`.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is incorrect. On Linux, `mmap` has an option `MAP_UNINITIALIZED`, which `malloc` may use for faster allocations.

Comment: thanks for your concise answer. Could you show me where the `malloc` calls `mmap`  with `MAP_UNINITIALIZED`, I checked the source code a couple of times, still couldn't find it

Comment: @slowjams: _The_ source code? You can't assume that particular `malloc` implementation is the only one in the world. The Microsoft `malloc` doesn't even call `mmap`.

Comment: @slowjams which source code did you checked? There is not _the_ `malloc` implementation, so if you want your code to be portable do not rely on implementation details that are not documented.

Comment: @MSalters so where I can check the code for `malloc`? I used Linux

Comment: @slowjams uClibc uses `MAP_UNINITIALIZED` in its `malloc` implementations for "no-mmu" systems. https://github.com/kraj/uClibc/blob/master/libc/stdlib/malloc-simple/alloc.c#L40

Comment: @IanAbbott I used desktop, so need to check glibc? but I still couldn't find MAP_UNINITIALIZED in malloc

Comment: @slowjams glibc doesn't use `MAP_UNINITIALIZED` for `malloc`.